# Switch statement and custom shortcode issue in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, switch-statement, shortcode

I am working on a Woocommerce shop, on the product page I want to be able to display multiple images by placing a shortcode in the text editor. the images are conditional and are only to be shown if the attribute called contains a specific value. I was able to create such a function, with using the switch statement to look for the value and display the image, if the value exsists.

Here is the code - it is placed in functions.php in my child theme.

```
   function display_colors_pic_sp() {
        $product = wc_get_product();
        $terms = get_terms("pa_color");
        foreach($terms as $term)
            switch ($term->name) {
                case "Blue RAL 5003":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Blue RAL 5010":
                    echo '<img src="example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Blue RAL 5013":
                    echo '<img src="https:example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_5013_e5005376-6410-479a-b526-f23ca5f13cb3_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Green RAL 6007":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_6007_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Grey RAL 7021":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_7032_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Grey RAL 7035":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_7035_f0d32a8d-7aac-45a8-97ec-cd46c8e35daf_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

                case "Black RAL 9005":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_9005_61462eeb-8b3d-4792-909b-fdb549d47e80_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

                case "White RAL 9010":
                    echo '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_9010_f80b4432-ba58-4377-821a-8ee8832a8610_1024x1024.jpg">';
                break;

            }


        }

    add_shortcode('colorpic', 'display_colors_pic_sp');
```

It works pretty much the way is it supposed to, and displays all the images based on the value, but for some reason no matter where I place the short-code. it appears in the top of the page, just right after the title regardless where I place the shortcode. I have another short-code which does something else and this one I can choose the position, by where I put the shortcode.

NOTE: 
If I change echo to return, the short-code appears where I want it to appear.
but then it only displays the first case for some reason, and not the other ones also that also contain a value. I have also tried removing "break;" after every case.

I would be very happy If somebody has the time and will to help me out and find out why the short-code gets positioned at the top of the page, and not where the short-code is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With shortcodes everything need to be always returned, but never echoed *(or print)*…

Also since WordPress 4.5.0 using [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function, taxonomies should be always passed via the 'taxonomy' argument in the $args array.

So what you can do is **turn on the buffering** using php [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) function this way:

```
function display_colors_pic_sp() {
    ob_start(); // Start buffering

    $path = content_url('/uploads/2019/04/');

    foreach( get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'pa_color') ) as $term) {
        switch ($term->name) {
            case "Blue RAL 5003":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Blue RAL 5010":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Blue RAL 5013":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_5013_e5005376-6410-479a-b526-f23ca5f13cb3_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Green RAL 6007":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_6007_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Grey RAL 7021":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_7032_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Grey RAL 7035":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_7035_f0d32a8d-7aac-45a8-97ec-cd46c8e35daf_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;

            case "Black RAL 9005":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_9005_61462eeb-8b3d-4792-909b-fdb549d47e80_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;

            case "White RAL 9010":
                echo '<img src="'.$path.'RAL_9010_f80b4432-ba58-4377-821a-8ee8832a8610_1024x1024.jpg">';
            break;
        }
    }
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return buffered content
}
add_shortcode('colorpic', 'display_colors_pic_sp');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works when returning it means the framework calls the function where it wants and expects you to return the values for it to place in the proper place. If you call `echo` that will just immediately send the value to the output and that's not going to work.

You can append all the HTML you want to have there into a variable and return that and it should fix the problem. So something like this:

```
function display_colors_pic_sp() {
    $ret = "";
    $product = wc_get_product();
    $terms = get_terms("pa_color");
    foreach($terms as $term)
        switch ($term->name) {
          case "Blue RAL 5003":
             $ret .= '<img src="https://example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
             break;
          case "Blue RAL 5010":
             $ret .= '<img src="example.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/RAL_5003_1024x1024-1.jpg">';
             break;
      ...
    return $ret;
}
```